# Randomize two lists by maintaining the sequence of mapping of values in the lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, shuffle

I have two lists

```
list1=['item1','item2','item3','item4']
list2=['label1','label2','label3','label4']
```

so there's a mapping between item and its labels. I want to shuffle them and produce the results such that the mapping is maintained on their index.

e.g.:

after shuffling

```
list1=['item4','item2','item1','item3']
list2=['label4','label2','label1','label3']
```

Comment: Why not combine the data in class or namedtuple?

Comment: I see zip is doing the same thing forming a tuple and randomizing it, thus maintaining the mapping

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary to solving your problem, I'm just wondering why you have the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import random

x = zip(list1, list2)
random.shuffle(x)

list1, list2 = zip(*x)
```

Then, for example, you have:

```
>>> list1
('item4', 'item3', 'item1', 'item2')

>>> list2
('label4', 'label3', 'label1', 'label2')
```

(These are tuples but they can be converted back to lists if needed.)